# Regex substitution using perl in application

Tags: regex, perl

I've to do a regex substitution and I'm using perl for that; which looks similar to this

> $ABC=~s/APP_*.*?_LOG_(.*?)_.*/$1/
>
> print "ABC=$ABC\n";

Where `$ABC` can be of below format before and after substitution:

```
APP_184_PRD_LOG_O2_2M -> O2
APP_184_PRD_CFC_O2_6D -> O2
APP_046_STG_CFC_BCK_4W_1 -> BCK
APP_050_STG_LOG_OSS_8M_2 -> OSS
APP_050_STG_LOG_SAM_SOX_2M -> SAM_SOX
APP_050_STG_CFC_SAM_FOR_6M_3 -> SAM_FOR

Rules:-
1st variable is always APP
4th variable can be LOG or CFC
We are concerned with variable no.5 or 6(in some cases)
If the 6th variable has Number+(W/D/M), then 6th & 7th variable to be removed
```

The substitution has to be a single liner (application restriction).

Comment: I don't see a question anywhere in your post.

Comment: @Hunter, sorry..if the question was not clear enough...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try either can you use negative lookahead or positive look ahead

Negative look ahead

`~s/APP.+?(?:LOG|CFC)_(.+?)_(?![^\d]).+/$1/`

Positive look ahead

`~s/APP.+?(?:LOG|CFC)_(.+?)_(?=\d).+/$1/g;`

```
while (<DATA>)
{
    $_ =~s/APP.+?(?:LOG|CFC)_(.+?)_(?![^\d]).+/$1/g;
    print $_;

}

__DATA__
APP_184_PRD_LOG_O2_2M
APP_184_PRD_CFC_O2_6D 
APP_046_STG_CFC_BCK_4W_1
APP_050_STG_LOG_OSS_8M_2 
APP_050_STG_LOG_SAM_SOX_2M 
APP_050_STG_CFC_SAM_FOR_6M_3
```

output

```
O2
O2
BCK
OSS
SAM_SOX
SAM_FOR
```

Comment: This is the regex (Negative lookback) that is working perfectly in the application as well as perl. I can't use the positive lookback as I can't put the "/g" at the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?![^\d+].*?)`, i.e :

```
^APP.*?(?:CFC|LOG)_(.*?)_(?![^\d+].*?)
```

---

**DEMO**

https://regex101.com/r/lE7oB7/1

Comment: Looks like it works fine with my requirement... testing it..

Comment: I've marked your reply as answer and it works good when I use it in normal perl command, but somehow, the regex (the negative lookback) is not working correct in the application. So, I'm checking other replies as well.

Comment: You may want to check if the subject is actually what you think it is. GL.

Answer (score 0):

This would do it too I think:

```
s/^APP_[^_]{3}_[^_]{3}_(?:LOG|CFC)_(.+)_\d[WMD](?:_\d+)?$/$1/;
```

Output:

```
$ perl -le 'for (@ARGV) { s/^APP_[^_]{3}_[^_]{3}_(?:LOG|CFC)_(.+)_\d[WMD](?:_\d+)?$/$1/; print }' APP_184_PRD_LOG_O2_2M APP_184_PRD_CFC_O2_6D APP_046_STG_CFC_BCK_4W_1 APP_050_STG_LOG_OSS_8M_2 APP_050_STG_LOG_SAM_SOX_2M APP_050_STG_CFC_SAM_FOR_6M_3
O2
O2
BCK
OSS
SAM_SOX
SAM_FOR
$
```

Comment: thanks for reply, the regex is not flexible enough due to character restriction {3} and at the end, if I add 2 digits, it fails again.